# SELECT count() with two same conditions

Tags: mysql

I have the following database. For each conversation, there are two participants. I would like to count the number of conversation_id when participant.participant_id = participantID1 and participant.participant_id = participantID2.

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
    `user_id` BIGINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `user_name` VARCHAR(16)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `conversation` (
    `conversation_id` BIGINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `user_id` BIGINT UNSIGNED,
    `time_started` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `time_closed` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(user_id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `participant` (
    `id` BIGINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `conversation_id` BIGINT UNSIGNED,
    `participant_id` BIGINT UNSIGNED,
    `time_joined` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `time_left` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    FOREIGN KEY (conversation_id) REFERENCES conversation(conversation_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (participant_id) REFERENCES users(user_id)
);
```

I tried something like but I ended up with count = 0:

```
SELECT count(conversation.conversation_id)
FROM `conversation`
INNER JOIN `participant` on participant.conversation_id = conversation.conversation_id
WHERE participant.participant_id = ? AND participant.participant_id = ?
```

I managed to do it differently but I would like to know if it is possible to do it in one single query. Thanks for your help! :-)

Comment: If I understand you correctly you're trying to get the count where participant_id is either participantID1 or participantID2. Why not use `participant_id IN (participantID1, participantID2)` construct?

Comment: You'll want to join the participant table twice (once for each participant id) and check each instance separately.

Comment: Hi Claudio, i try to get the count where participant_id is participantID1 AND participantID2 (two participants in the same conversation)

Comment: got it Minh Pham, I missunderstood your requirements. In this case @miken32 suggestion is what you need to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't check this at the moment, but something like this should work:

```
SELECT count(c.conversation_id)
FROM conversation c
INNER JOIN participant p1 ON p1.conversation_id = c.conversation_id
INNER JOIN participant p2 ON p2.conversation_id = c.conversation_id
WHERE p1.participant_id = ? AND p2.participant_id = ?
```

Comment: I think I'd use an `OR` instead of an `AND`, since it's likely that (at least sometimes) there are two different participants in a conversation.

Comment: The question specifically asked for conversations where both IDs were participants, hence the AND.

Comment: I didn't interpret it that way, but okay. My bad.